# google json api search results limit, not 100 search queries per day

Tags: json, search

The Google Custom Search API requires the use of an API key, I have get from the Google APIs console. The API provides 100 search queries per day for free. I want to more,so I have signed up for billing in the console and succeed.I can set the requests/day,defalut 1000 requests/day.But the total results are still 100,I show 10 in one page,so I can get 10 pages.
Billing solve the querys per day,but not the total results.The document does not explain clearly.What should i do to solve the results problem.Does XML API have the same problem? Must I Replace the JSON API by XML API?

Comment: Good question. I would also like to know the answer to this!

Answer (score 0):

another year passed... Limits are the same =((
Google forces us to use multiple accounts to get complete search results.

Use a query per day/week/month.
Or you can sort huge result array by publish date. And when '100-items' limit is reached you should execute new request with excluding first items by applying "the lowest(or the highest) possible value" condition on publish date.

btw, using webbrowser you could set 100 results per page. So total count of result items is 1000 per query. Web crawling would be helpful=))))

be happy!

Comment: Thank you very much. Now we maybe only solve the problem by xml API,it can show 100 hundred pages. Your solution setting 100 results is a good idea.

Comment: Yesterday i was glad to find XML Api on **Yandex.com**. I bound my phone number to account and set search type to 'world wide'. Now I can process 10000 queries per day with 1000 results in each other.